# How to use array values for launch parameters?

Tags: arrays, bash

i am trying to write a script for launch Steam Native For Windows, via PlayOnLinux. Just with videogames have a Microsoft Windows Binary Executable only.

Reading the "ID" from a list, is the ID its not in the list then launch Steam native for GNU/Linux.

The idea of this script is for use it with a Web Browser for example : Mozilla Firefox using the "steam://" protocol.

i put my script here (i am from Venezuela, and the script is make it on Spanish, if its possible, please don't translate the variables) :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo '
Autor ----------------> Inukaze ( Venezuela )
Licensia -------------> GPL 2

******* Inicio : Acerca de este Script ********

 Este Mini-Script es para poder iniciar Steam
 Para Windows, desde un Navegador Web Nativo
 para Liñux.

 La idea y la funcion es para facilitar la 
 Instalación de varios Videojuegos que no
 poseen una version nativa para Liñux

 Iniciando el Steam que tengas en el prefijo
 "Steam" dentro de "PlayOnLinux" e iniciando
 y encolando la descarga de (los) titulo(s)
 que hayas hecho clic en el navegador

******** Fin : Acerca de este Script **********
'

# Obtener el Nombre del Nucleo
Nucleo=$(uname -s)
case "$Nucleo" in
    Linux)      Nucleo="linux"                      ;;
    FreeBSD)    Nucleo="kfreebsd"                   ;;
    GNU/kFreeBSD)   Nucleo="kfreebsd"                   ;;
    * ) echo "Tu Sistema Operativo -> NO ESTA SOPORTADO"            ;;
esac

# Obtener la ARQUITECTURA
ARQUITECTURA=$(uname -m)
case "$ARQUITECTURA" in
    x86)    ARQUITECTURA="x86"                      ;;
    i?86)   ARQUITECTURA="x86"                      ;;
    amd64)  ARQUITECTURA="amd64"                        ;;
    x86_64) ARQUITECTURA="amd64"                        ;;
    * ) echo    "Tú Arquitectura : '$ARQUITECTURA' : -> IT NOT SUPPORTED."  ;;
esac

# Comprobrar que (No/)Existen los archivos y rutas, antes de proceder
if test -d "$HOME/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Steam"
    then
    echo
            if test -f "$HOME/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Steam/drive_c/Program Files/Steam/steam.exe"
            then
                echo "Encontrado ejecutable de Steam en el prefijo predeterminado"
            fi

            if test -d "$HOME/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Steam/drive_c/Program Files/Steam/steamapps/common"
            then
                echo "Encontrada Carpeta Comun de Steam"
            fi
    else
        echo "Steam no esta instalado en el Prefijo Predeterminado"
        xmessage -timeout 3 "Steam no esta instalado en el Prefijo Predeterminado"
        exit 1
fi

if test -f "$HOME/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Steam/playonlinux.cfg"
    then
    # Obtener la version de WINE y su arquitectura del Prefijo Steam dentro de PlayOnLinux ;
    VERSION_WINE=$(cat "$HOME/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Steam/playonlinux.cfg" | grep VERSION= | sed 's/VERSION=//g')
    ARQUITECTURA_WINE=$(cat "$HOME/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Steam/playonlinux.cfg" | grep ARCH= | sed 's/ARCH=//g')
    else
        echo "Steam no esta instalado en el Prefijo Predeterminado"
        xmessage -timeout 3 "Steam no esta instalado en el Prefijo Predeterminado"
        exit 1
fi

# Configurar Variables de Entornos, Rutas e Iniciar Steam para Windows :
PATH="$HOME/.PlayOnLinux/wine/$ARQUITECTURA-$ARQUITECTURA_WINE/$VERSION_WINE/bin:$PATH"
export WINESERVER="$HOME/.PlayOnLinux/wine/$Nucleo-$ARQUITECTURA_WINE/$VERSION_WINE/bin/wineserver"
export WINELOADER="$HOME/.PlayOnLinux/wine/$Nucleo-$ARQUITECTURA_WINE/$VERSION_WINE/bin/wine"
export WINEDLLPATH="$HOME/.PlayOnLinux/wine/$Nucleo-$ARQUITECTURA_WINE/$VERSION_WINE/lib"
export WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Steam"
export WINEDEBUG=-all
cd "$HOME/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/Steam/drive_c/./Program Files/Steam"

# Lista de Videojuegos segun su IDentificador de APPlicacion en STEAM :
STEAMID=( 
"204360"    # Castle Crashers(TM)
"205230"    # Hell Yeah! Wrath of the Dead Rabbit
"205950"    # Jet Set Radio (Puede que necesites intercambiar el nombre de ambos ejecutables)
"215100"    # Ragnarok Online
"218640"    # Lucius
"22000"     # World Of Goo                  - Ya esta Portado a Liñux
"222900"    # Dead Island: Epidemic             - La Pagina de la tienda ya no existe
"224220"    # Pressure
"235720"    # Cubetractor
"253900"    # Knights and Merchants
"254000"    # East India Company Gold           - La Pagina de la tienda ya no existe
"254040"    # Pirates Of Black Cove Gold            - La Pagina de la tienda ya no existe
"254060"    # KnightShift
"254100"    # World War II: Panzer Claws
"258200"    # Talisman: Prologue
"259320"    # Heli Heroes
"267920"    # Gun Metal
"267940"    # Glacier 3: The Meltdown
"267960"    # Hyper Fighters
"267980"    # Hostile Waters: Antaeus Rising
"271640"    # Humanity Asset
"274900"    # Murder Miners
"278490"    # Aveyond 3-2: Gates of Night
"279640"    # The Troma Project
"283330"    # Desert Thunder
"283350"    # Eurofighter Typhoon
"283410"    # CT Special Forces: Fire for Effect
"284950"    # Pixel Puzzles: Japan
"285840"    # Enemy Mind
"286440"    # Rover Rescue
"292380"    # Racer 8
"292390"    # Realms Of The Hauting (DOSBox)
"292410"    # Street Racing Syndicate
"293180"    # Overcast - Walden and the Werewolf
"296910"    # 8BitBoy TM
"306350"    # Slipstream 5000
"307070"    # Memories of a Vagabond
"307350"    # Nux
"310450"    # Steam & Steel : Episode 1
"311480"    # Vertical Drop Heroes HD
"315430"    # Polarity
"319180"    # Platypus II
"321150"    # Melissa K. and the Heart of Gold Collector's Edition
"323630"    # Ubinota
"331710"    # Why So Evil
"34270"     # SEGA MegaDrive & Genesis Classics     - La Pagina de la tienda ya no existe
"343360"    # Particula
"344040"    # Voxelized
"344130"    # Cataegis : The White Wind
"347560"    # Terra Incognita ~ Chapter One: The Descendant
"350810"    # Pixel Puzzles 2: Anime
"351030"    # Pixel Puzzles Ultimate
"351470"    # Sometimes: Success Requires Sacrifice
"3590"      # Plants -VS- Zombies GOTY
"37400"     # Time Gentlemen, Please! and Ben There, Dan That! Special Edition Double Pack
"37420"     # Time Gentlemen, Please! and Ben There, Dan That! Special Edition Double Pack
"382490"    # Relic Hunters Zero
"385200"    # Absconding Zatwor
"395170"    # DISTRAINT
"395980"    # Break Into Zatwor
"410560"    # Trinium Wars
"42500"     # DogFighter
"428430"    # Endorlight
"447880"    # Beast Blaster
"4720"      # Condemned: Criminal Origins
"517320"    # GunGirl2
"57690"     # Tropico 4: Steam Special Edition
"6850"      # Hitman 2: Silent Assassin
"7510"      # X-Blades
"7520"      # Two Worls II
#"91200"    # Anomaly: Warzone Earth            - Ya esta Portado a Liñux
#"200710"   # TorchLight II                 - Ya esta Portado a Liñux
#"238910"   # Bionic Dues ( Ya portado a Liñux )
#"253920"   # Gorky 17                  - Usa su propia version de Wine
#"253940"   # Septerra Core                 - Usa su propia version de Wine
#"253980"   # Enclave                   - Usa su propia version de Wine
#"254020"   # Commander : Conquest Of the Americas Gold - La Pagina de la tienda ya no existe
#"259280"   # Earth 2150 : The Moon Project         - La Pagina de la tienda ya no existe
#"259300"   # Earth 2150 : Lost Souls           - La Pagina de la tienda ya no existe
#"259360"   # Chicken Shoot 2               - La Pagina de la tienda ya no existe
#"278460"   # SkyBorn                   - Ya esta Portado a Liñux
#"382240"   # Blood Of Old (OLD VERSION)            - La Pagina de la tienda ya no existe
#"38740"    # EDGE                      - Ya esta Portado a Liñux
#"48000"    # LIMBO (Ya esta Portado a Liñux)
)

# En caso de que el parametro posea algun numero de la lista
# Iniciar el Steam Nativo para Windows desde PlayOnLinux :

         #IDEA 1 :
         #IDEA1#STEAMWIN=$(exec wine Steam.exe -no-dwrite -no-cef-sandbox "$1" &> /dev/null)
         #IDEA1#    case $1 in
         #IDEA1#    steam://run/3590) if [ "$1" = "$@"]; then $STEAMWIN; fi ;;
         #IDEA1#    esac
         #IDEA 2 :
         #while (( ${#STEAMID[@]}+1 ))
         #do
         #
         #IDEA 3 :
         #  for i in ${!STEAMID[*]}; do
         #
         #IDEA 4 :
         # if [ "${STEAMID[*]}" = "$@" ]; then

            case $1 in
            *)
                    echo
                    echo 'Parametro de Lanzamiento -> '"$@"''
                    echo
                    exec wine Steam.exe -no-dwrite -no-cef-sandbox "$@" &> /dev/null
                    echo
                    echo
                    exit 0
                    ;;
            esac

            # En caso de usar do, finalizar con "done" :
            #done

# En caso de que el parametro no pesea ningun numero de la lista
# Iniciar el Steam Nativo para Liñux

        # Correcion para Steam para que me deje de dar errores como :
        # Could not find required OpenGL entry point :
        # 'glColorMaskIndexedEXT'
        # 'GLGetError'!
        # 'glUseProgramStages'!
        #
        export PATH="/media/Compartido/Videojuegos/Gestor/Linux/Steam/Slackware64/home/bin/":$PATH
        export GAME_DEBUGGER="hl2debug"
    hl2debug
```

Comment: can you extract the part that you have problem with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you wish to check whether some `id` is contained within the array `STEAMID`, then all you need is a simple comparison in bash using the `=~` operator with `[[ ... ]]`. For example to check for `id=321150`, you can use something like:

```
id=321150
[[ ${STEAMID[@]} =~ $id ]] && echo "start windows: $id" || echo "use Gnu"
```

If `id=321150` exists in `STEAMID` (it does), so the `echo "start windows: $id"` would execute, otherwise the `echo "use Gnu"` would execute. You can adapt as required, using `if ... then ... else ... fi` instead of the *compound statement* if you like. But that is how I would check whether the `id` exists in the `STEAMID` array for purposes of windows/linux launch of `steam://` if I understood your question.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ id=321150; [[ ${STEAMID[@]} =~ $id ]] && echo "start windows: $id"
start windows: 321150
```

If you are looking for something else, and I did not correctly understand the question, drop a comment and I'm happy to help further.

Comment: Yes i am searching a method for example when i run from my web browser the line 

"steam://run/517320" 

From the site "http://store.steampowered.com/app/517320/GunGirl_2/" when i click on "Play" an after on "Yes, i had steam installed"

Use the script for Launch Steam for Windows native version. via PlayOnLinux, in the script yes using the ID for compare really exist on the script, and if the ID don't exist, launch with Steam for GNU/Linux native. the idea is simple, but for me is hard to apply it

Comment: If you examine the script above, it does just that, using your existing `STEAMID` array to search for a given `id`, and if found, add your start windows code where I did a simple `echo "start windows $id`, if nothing matches, then start Linux where I have `echo "use Gnu"`. You are just using `[[ ${STEAMID[@]} =~ $id ]]` to test if `id` matches any element in `STEAMID`.

Comment: Did you post line `219`? (e.g. `"/usr/bin/inupolwine-steam.sh: línea 219`)? You should also make sure `"$@"` only contains a single argument in `[[ ${STEAMID[@]} =~ $@ ]]`, like  `[[ ${STEAMID[@]} =~ $1 ]]` (or whatever the `id` is. That's why I set the `id` variable. (this may apply where you are passing `"$@"` in other places. Make sure you know what is contained in the parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much, its working i put the follow line : 

The line 219 is this : 

`[[ "${STEAMID[@]}" =~ "$@" ]] && $(exec wine Steam.exe -no-dwrite -no-cef-sandbox "$@" &> /dev/null) || $(steam "$@" &> /dev/null) || exit 0 ` . Now is working :D

Comment: This will work only in this particular example. What if the `id` will be for example `id=3` or `id=351`? here isn't `351` element but the regex will find it as substring.

Comment: Good catch, If there is a possibility of matching a substring, then using `if echo ${STEAMID[@]} | grep -w "$id"; then ...` to use a *whole-word* match for `id`.